# Object comparison in Javascript using equals and compareTo methods

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement custom equality and relational operations using equals and compareTo methods. However, I get wrong results. Please help me figure our where I'm doing wrong.

```
var Person = function () {
this.age = null;
this.name = null;
};

Person.prototype.equals = function (that) {
    if (this.age === that.age) return true;
    else return false;
    };

Person.prototype.compareTo = function (that) {
    return this.age - that.age;
    };

var p1 = new Person();
var p2 = new Person();

p1.age = 10;
p2.age = 20;

document.writeln(p1 < p2); // this should be true but evaluates to false.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have operator overloading, and `>` doesn't call any methods on your objects, so `p1 < p2` won't use your `equals` or `compareTo`.

To do that comparison, you'd use:

```
document.writeln(p1.compareTo(p2) < 0);
```

That said, you can implement `valueOf` and have it return `age`. `valueOf` *does* get called as part of `>` between objects:

```
function Person(age) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = null;
}

Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, "valueOf", {
    value: function () {
        return this.age;
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
});
```

Or in code written since ES2015 became universally-supported in non-obsolete browsers:

```
class Person {
    constructor(age) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = null;
    }

    valueOf() {
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
class Person {
    constructor(age) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = null;
    }

    valueOf() {
        return this.age;
    }
}

const p1 = new Person(10);
const p2 = new Person(20);

console.log("p1 < p2: " + (p1 < p2)); // true
console.log("p1 > p2: " + (p1 > p2)); // false
```

**Beware though that `p1 == p2` and `p1 === p2` will always be `false`**, even if `age` is the same:

```js
class Person {
    constructor(age) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = null;
    }

    valueOf() {
        return this.age;
    }
}

const p1 = new Person(10); // Same age
const p2 = new Person(10); // Same age

console.log("p1 == p2:  " + (p1 == p2));  // false!
console.log("p1 === p2: " + (p1 === p2)); // false!
```

`valueOf` is invoked when the JavaScript engine needs to convert the object to a primitive; it doesn't do that for `==` or `===` unless it has to because the other operand is a primitive. So you'd have to define `equals` and explicitly call it (`p1.equals(p2)`), or force the comparison to be between the primitives (`+p1 === +p2`), which is error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting this question and working with node v18.13.0, I found that relational operators between objects invoke the `valueOf` method, and if not available, then invoke the `toString` method. A `String` representation can be built to allow comparison of most object types (assuming you can build the String representation as needed).

The following example illustrates all these cases by commenting in/out the two versions of `toString` or the `valueOf` method:

```
import assert from 'node:assert/strict';

export class ComparableDate {

    // private instance variables
    #year
    #month
    #date

    constructor(year, month, date) {
        this.#year = year;
        this.#month = month;
        this.#date = date;
    }

    // Relational operators > < invoke the toString method.
    // Observe that this fails for comparing dates in general
    // toString() {
    //     console.log("toString invoked");
    //     return ""+this.#year+"-"+this.#month+"-"+this.#date;
    // }

    // Zero-left padding, makes the string comparison work as expected
    toString() {
        console.log("toString invoked");
        return (""+this.#year).padStart(4,'0')+"-"+(""+this.#month).padStart(2,'0')+"-"+(""+this.#date).padStart(2,'0');
    }


    // valueOf called over toString if present
    valueOf() {
        console.log("valueOf invoked");
        return this.#date + this.#month*31 + this.#year*366;
    }

}


// Test dates
let d1 = new ComparableDate(2023,2,15);
let d2 = new ComparableDate(2023,10,31);

// Test cases
assert(d2>d1, `${d2} must be greater than ${d1}`);
assert(d1<d2, `${d1} must be less than ${d2}`);
```

Comment: Btw, `ComparableDate` is not a good example or at least has a weird name, since a basic normal `Date` already is comparable.

Comment: Thanks to Bergi for pointing out my typo. Fixed accordingly.